# Popups appearing empty intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using intellij idea 14.1.7,

`$ java -version 
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)`.

Linux : Ubuntu 14.04

When I try to open a project, insert something,find something or anything that opens a popup/dialog box it appears like :

[image]

I have tried finding solution but I didn't got anything. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `MD` would indicate Markdown. Do you have a Markdown plugin for IntelliJ? Does it need updating? I suggest also raising an issue on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) about the Graphical issue.

Comment: MD is the name of the module. Markdown plugin is not installed in my intellij.

Comment: Sometimes graphical rendering issues can be worked around by `Alt`+`Tab`bing away and back to the window. When it next occurs try that and seeing what the window is, then update your YouTrack ticket with screenshots and your workaround.

Comment: Alt+Tab didn't worked. I have raised it on youtrack, link : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157641

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was some graphic issue in unity. I installed Ubuntu mate environment in Unity and now I am using it around 2 weeks the blank/transparent issue didn't came.
But there are other issues which are quite small, like content assist some times don't appear. But dialog/popup boxes are appearing normally now.